# Ipad/Iphone - Rotation in UIView with images an all

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, core-graphics, rotation

How rotate UIView with full of contents. I am getting problem in rotation of UIViews. Can any one help me out??? please give me some like with step by step example.

Comment: Which type of rotation you are talking about? Orientation change?

Comment: rotation when we rotate Iphone/Ipad Landscape & Portrait i am getting problem with interface it shows different behaviour. If user rotate it's ipad/iphone view should be change according rotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

```
myUIView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
```

That will turn the whole thing 90 degrees to the right, contents and all.
The argument to CGAffineTransformMakeRotation is in radians...

Comment: Thanks a lot but i am still getting problem in image rotation its not displays properly view is moving properly.??

Comment: I'd also put a black background color on your window too just to be safe. I had a problem with white lines while rotating and changing my window background to black fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey thanks a lot for your response. Stuff which are related to rotation are solved but still i have few problems in Landscape mode i am using this code to animate Two UIViews but in Landscape Mode One view is not appearing i want an ideal solution for this.

Rotation Code which i am currently using...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:)   name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

}


- (void)didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[notification object] orientation];

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 
    {

        CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0,0, 1024, 748);
        self.view.bounds = contentRect;
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0)];
    } 
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {

        CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0,0, 1024, 748);
        self.view.bounds = contentRect; 


        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / -2.0)];
    }

    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
    {

        CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0,0, 768, 1024);
        self.view.bounds = contentRect;
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI)];
    } 
    else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {

        CGRect contentRect = CGRectMake(0,0, 768, 1024);
        self.view.bounds = contentRect;
        [self.view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)];
    }


}
```

UIView amination code.

```
self.loginView.hidden=NO;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
self.AcTypeView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 493);
[UIView commitAnimations];



[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

self.loginView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -700);
[UIView commitAnimations];




Thanks!!!!
```